# Gradient Background for TabBar?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to make the background of the TabNavigator be a gradient. The documentation at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/colors.html indicates that *color properties usually match how CSS works on the web*. I went to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient and read that *Because s belong to the  data type, they can only be used where s can be used. For this reason, linear-gradient() won't work on background-color and other properties that use the  data type.*

Consequently, the following *won't* work:

```
import { TabNavigator, TabBarBottom } from 'react-navigation';

export default TabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
    },
  . . .
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ....
    tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    animationEnabled: false,
    swipeEnabled: false,
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'rgb(111, 111, 111)',
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 12,
      },
      style: {
        backgroundColor: 'linear-gradient(45deg, blue, red)',
      },
    }
  }
);
```

Which is clear from the documentation. What *isn't clear* is what will work.

Update:

Clearly the regularly accepted practice is to create your own tab bar. Or, in my case, to tell the designer that he was out of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace the `tabBarComponent` with your own component, and there use [react-native-linear-gradient](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient).

Comment: Need set backgroundColor: 'transparent', as following

       `tabBarOptions: {
               style: {
                   backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                     }
              }`

Answer (score 2):

you can use this

```
<Tab.Navigator 
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false,
    tabBarActiveTintColor: '#fff',
    tabBarStyle:{position:'absolute', height:55} ,
    tabBarBackground:() =>(
      <LinearGradient  colors={['#AD3231',  '#2757C3']} style={{height:70,borderTopLeftRadius:15,borderTopRightRadius:15}}/>
    )
  }}>
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: Also had to add shadowColor: "transparent" in tabBarStyle